# How to send data immediately when receiving from server to html page in a web application

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, web-applications, client-server

I'm trying to make an online whiteboard.
The process is: a manager creates a whiteboard, and clients will enter manager's username to enter his whiteboard.
So when a client sends request to server, server will send message to manager to inform a client wants to connect.
I created a Java class to handle these requests:

```
class ReceiveRequest extends Thread{
  ...
  public void run(){
    while(true){
     message = DataInputStrem.readline();
     //JSONObject-jsonObj represents message
     jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(message);
     if(jsonObj.get("request").equals("connecting"))//a client wants to connect
     {
        System.out.println(jsonObj); //I can see the json object at console window
        //handle connecting request, how to display this request to the manager?
     }
    }
  }
}
```

So how can i display something like an alert at html page(DrawingBoard.html) that a client wants to connect, accept or not, every time the server sends connecting request? This java class is not a servlet so i cannot do something like set request attribute and forward page...
Thank u everyone.

More details: I've got a web page to let user creates their own whiteboard or join an available whiteboard. If user chooses to join a WB, a request is sent to the server, the server will sent this request to the manager of this WB. The class above is on the client side(the Whiteboard web application), it can receive a JSONObject that represents the request for the user who wants to join existing WB(the jsonObj object above). This jsonobject has a property called "request", if the property is equals to "Connecting" it means that an user wants to join this WB, so I want to ask how to display this notification to the manager of this WB

Comment: Why don't you use `sockets` or `node.js`?  (I know it's not java - at least for node.js - but I think will be good for what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: @Oscar: I'm just doing my client side. I know node.js and websockets seem to be good but not enough time to learn new technology.

Answer (score 0):

Please put more details in your question.

I can just assume that Whiteboard Manager is an application with ServerSocket listening on some port and Client is application with client Socket that will connect on that port. When client connects to port on server, server knows that client has connected and there on communication/data can happen over IO streams obtained from those sockets.